# Python numpy.fft very slow (10x slower) when run in subprocess

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, fft

I've found that numpy.fft.fft (and its variants) very slow when run in the background.  Here is an example of what I'm talking about

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mproc
import time
import sys

# the producer function, which will run in the background and produce data
def Producer(dataQ):
    numFrames = 5
    n = 0
    while n < numFrames:
        data = np.random.rand(3000, 200)
        dataQ.put(data)   # send the datta to the consumer
        time.sleep(0.1)  # sleep for 0.5 second, so we dont' overload CPU
        n += 1            

# the consumer function, which will run in the backgrounnd and consume data from the producer
def Consumer(dataQ):
    while True:
        data = dataQ.get()
        t1 = time.time()
        fftdata = np.fft.rfft(data, n=3000*5)
        tDiff = time.time() - t1
        print("Elapsed time is %0.3f" % tDiff)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        sys.stdout.flush()

# the main program  if __name__ == '__main__': is necessary to prevent this code from being run
# only when this program is started by user
if __name__ == '__main__':     
    data = np.random.rand(3000, 200)
    t1 = time.time()
    fftdata = np.fft.rfft(data, n=3000*5, axis=0)
    tDiff = time.time() - t1
    print("Elapsed time is %0.3f" % tDiff)

    # generate a queue for transferring data between the producedr and the consumer
    dataQ = mproc.Queue(4)

    # start up the processoso
    producerProcess = mproc.Process(target=Producer, args=[dataQ], daemon=False)
    consumerProcess = mproc.Process(target=Consumer, args=[dataQ], daemon=False)
    print("starting up processes")

    producerProcess.start()
    consumerProcess.start()
    time.sleep(10) # let program run for 5 seconds

    producerProcess.terminate()
    consumerProcess.terminate()
```

The output it produes on my machine:

```
Elapsed time is 0.079
starting up processes
Elapsed time is 0.859
Elapsed time is 0.861
Elapsed time is 0.878
Elapsed time is 0.863
Elapsed time is 0.758
```

As you can see, it is roughly 10x slower when run in the background, and I can't figure out why this would be the case. The time.sleep() calls should ensure that the other process (the main process and producer process) aren't doing anything when the FFT is being computed, so it should use all the cores. I've checked CPU utilization through Windows Task Manager and it seems to use up about 25% when numpy.fft.fft is called heavily in both the single process and multiprocess cases.

Anyone have an idea whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that your fft call in the background thread is:

```
fftdata = np.fft.rfft(data, n=3000*5)
```

rather than:

```
fftdata = np.fft.rfft(data, n=3000*5, axis=0)
```

which for me made all the difference.

There are a few other things worth noting. Rather than having the `time.sleep()` everywhere, why not just let the processor take care of this itself? Further more, rather than suspending the main thread, you can use

```
consumerProcess.join()
```

and then have the producer process run `dataQ.put(None)` once it has finished loading the data, and break out of the loop in the consumer process, i.e.:

```
def Consumer(dataQ):
    while True:
        data = dataQ.get()
        if(data is None):
            break
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, I realized this a shoft time I have a posted.   numpy.fft defaults along the last axis, so I'm not doing the fft the same way.    The real problem was that for certain input sizes, numpy.fft is very slow.   But in my case, I can zero pad to a close power of 2 (like nfftpts = int(2 ** np.round(np.log2(nfftpts))), to get around this problem

Comment: As for time.sleep(), I have found without it, the CPU usage jumps pretty high.  This is only a test program, but in the real, much more complciated program, the processes are always running, until they get a shutdown messsage.  But they're not always collecting data.  The real program is basically used for asynchrous data collection, processing and display, to speed things up because Python threads aren't concurrent, so to get the speed advantage the only approach that made sense to me is multiple processes.